# What is a set of chromosome and what is a pair of chromosome

Tags: genetics

What is the definition of **set of chromosomes**? Does it differ from **pair of chromosomes**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes those two expressions refer to different things.

**Set of chromosome**

The term "set of chromosome" refers to ploidy number. A haploid has one set of chromosome, a diploid has two sets of chromosomes, an hexaploid has six sets of chromosomes.

In humans, each set of chromosome is made of 23 chromosomes (22 autosomes and 1 sex chromosome).

**Pair of chromosome**

A pair of chromosome refers to the two homologous chromosomes in a diploid individual (one chromosome from each set for a given chromosome number).

**Source of information**

If the above is unclear, then you should have a look at any intro course to genetic such as [these courses by Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/biology/classical-genetics) for example.

Comment: Plz clarify this a bit more. 1- Does each set of chromosome come from mother and father in a PAIR of chromosome?  2- Chromatid - a single chromosome in a newly copied pair - Do Two Chromatid contain the Identical DNA  sequence ?

Comment: 1) Yes, although most of the time, we don't know which chromosome of a pair comes from which parent (we don't know which chromosome of a pair belong to which set). 2) Yes. There are many related posts to this second question of yours. E.g. see [What are homologous chromosomes?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59287/what-are-homologous-chromosomes) or [Chromosome and chromatid numbers during cell cycle phases](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29656/chromosome-and-chromatid-numbers-during-cell-cycle-phases). Feel free to open a new post if you've got more questions.